# Mapkit Annotations : remove old, add new and keep existing

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm dynamically loading annotations on a mapview. When the user reload the annotations, i want to remove the old (the ones that are not anymore returns by the WS), add the new ones (that's ok), and keep the existing ones (if i remove everything, there is a "blink" effect).

What's the proper and good way to do this ?
I was going to do this way : 
1. Browse existing annotations, remove the ones which are not in the results of WS
2. Browse the new ones, look if they are on the map already (and updating them), if not, adding them on the map.

Looks like a lot of array browsing to me (we talk about 100 annotations, at least), i was thinking maybe there is a cleaner, quicker way to do ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

100 is not that much. You'd only need one loop to remove them though, you wouldn't need to check if the new ones were there if you'd already removed all the ones that weren't in the new set.

Comment: Let's say there is 1, 2, 3, 4 on the map. The user call the webservices, and it returns 3, 4, 5, 6. I need to remove 1 and 2, i need to do an add on 5 and 6, but i can't add 3 and 4 because they are already here. If i do "addAnnotation", it will be a "blink" effect, really not "eye candy".

Comment: You could do it like this. for (anno in oldList) { posInNewList = [newlist positionOf:anno]; if (posInNewList == -1) [oldList remove:anno]; else [newlist remove:anno];}  You'd need to find an efficient way of finding the old annotations in your new list. If the new list length is expected to be much shorter than the oldList a quick inner loop would probably be ok. This doesn't update the old annotation, but you can add that pretty easily. The point is to remove them from the old list or the new list in the same loop.